# Mapping Values from one file to another using Bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

So I have two files, namely listed below, I've just added 2 examples however I have almost 100 lines in file1 which is in the format listed below.

Idea is the variables of file2 is used as a source to one of our internal script, at the moment we are manually populating the data from file1 into file2 as we are manually mapping the values.

I wanted to know if this can be achieved by Bash scripting to identify keywords of file1 and match them to keywords of file2 and append the values of those matched keywords of file1 into the matched keys of file2.

File 1

```
system-service:10/AF/GH/100-2020
mint-value-daemon:10/GH/KL-19GA1-2020
event-count-svc:10/LL/GH/LL-2020
node-daemon:ABCD_201612_1900_139
```

File 2

```
MINT_SERVICE=10/GH/KL-19GA1-2020 //value2 from file1
SYSTEM_SERVICE=10/AF/GH/100-2020 //Value1 from file1
EVENT_SERVICE=svc:10/LL/GH/LL-2020 //value3 from file1
NODE_SERVER_TAG=ABCD_201612_1900_139 //value 4 from file1
```

**NOTE:** Just an heads-up the keywords in file1 are usually 2-3 words with hypens, so I was thinking of a partial match of keywords like event from file2 to event from file1 and get the respective value.

Comment: Would a case-insensitive match on the first word (separated by `_`/`-`) work for you?

Comment: Also, you've described the expected result for File 2, but how would it be in its initial state? lines of `VAR_NAME=` with an empty value? If a value is already present, should it be updated based on File 1?

Comment: match of any case should be file, as I need to only populate data into file2. And in many cases, the file2 is usually having the old data. So yes, we need to overwrite the previous values.

Answer (score 1):

If `file2` needs to be created from scratch:

```
awk -F: -v OFS='=' '{
    split($1, a, "-")
    print toupper(a[1])"_SERVICE", $2
}' file1 > file2
```

If `file2` already has variables that need to be overwritten:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
awk -F: -v OFS='=' '{
    if (FNR == NR) {
        split($1, a, "-")
        var[toupper(a[1])] = $2
    } else {
        split($0, a, "=")
        split(a[1], b, "_")
        if (var[b[1]] != "") {
            print a[1], var[b[1]]
        } else {
            print
        }
    }
}' file1 file2 > file2_new

mv file2_new file2
```

## Second snippet explaination:

1) `awk` loops through the input files line by line.
2) While doing so, $0 contains the value of complete line. $1, $2, $3… contain individual `:` delimited values. We asked `:` to be delimeter in arg `-F:`.
3) NR is a variable the contains the line number that it is currently on.
4) As we are inputting 2 files to awk, it's a little different. `NR` resets to 0 when we go to next file.
`FNR` is a variable that would keep on incrementing regardless of the file it's going through.
5) Conditional check `FNR == NR` means that we are on the first file.

Taking example from file1, let's say we were on line

```
mint-value-daemon:10/GH/KL-19GA1-2020
```

```
$0 = mint-value-daemon:10/GH/KL-19GA1-2020
$1 = mint-value-daemon
$2 = 10/GH/KL-19GA1-2020
```

6) In this conditional statement we use split() function to split $1 by `-` into an array named `a`.

So basically this line:

```
split($1, a, "-")
```

Gives us:

```
a[1] = mint
a[2] = value
a[3] = daemon
```

We use an associative array now, named `var`.

```
var[toupper(a[1])] = $2
```

This stores value of `$2` in at the key `MINT` i.e.

```
var["MINT"] = 10/GH/KL-19GA1-2020
```

Going so, it stores value of every such element in file1.

When condition `FNR == NR` goes false i.e. we start traversing through 2nd file, we follow a similar approach.

Remember file separator is still `:`, and it is not the separator in file2.

So in else:

Let's say we were on line:

```
MINT_SERVICE=10/GH/KL-19GA1-2020 //value2 from file1
```

We use:

```
split($0, a, "=")
```

Which gives us:

```
a[1] = MINT_SERVICE
a[2] = 10/GH/KL-19GA1-2020 //value2 from file1
```

Then on `a[1]` we again use split based on `_`.

```
split(a[1], b, "_")
```

This gives us:

```
b[1] = MINT
b[2] = SERVICE
```

Now:

```
if (var[b[1]] != "") {
    print a[1], var[b[1]]
} else {
    print
}
```

In array `var` in which we stored values when `FNR == NR` was true,

We check if

```
var["MINT"] != ""
```

if this holds true,

```
print a[1], var[b[1]]
```

which prints:

```
MINT_SERVICE=10/GH/KL-19GA1-2020
```

The reason for `=` is the `-v OFS='='` which is the separator of `print`.

in the else:

```
print
```

which is same as

```
print $0
```

i.e. if this value if not a key in `var` print it without any modification.

---

All this output goes to `file2_new`.

In the end we rename `file2_new` to `file2`.

Comment: if you observe the line 4 which i added in both the files, this should give you an idea that only the word prior to the first 'underscore' needs to be matched and only value needs to be appended in file2.

also can you explain the logic for your 2 code, i can also give it a hand.

Comment: @theborngeek, I have corrected that issue and explained it. HTH